# Как сделать заливку фигур в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

Как в tkinter можно делать заливку фигур как на фото?

[image: brushes]

Comment: Надо написать соответствующий каждой картинке программный код.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример заполнения кружочками. Остальное думайте по аналогии.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x500+400+200')
canvas = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_rectangle(20, 20, 300, 300, fill='green')
for i in range(20, 300, 20):
    for j in range(20, 300, 20):
        canvas.create_oval(i, j, i + 5, j + 5, fill='red')

window.mainloop()
```